# Framework7: Link on swiper slider not redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I have a link present on a slide on my swiper slider to go to a file called year.html

link:

```
<a href="year.html">Add by year, make & model</a>
```

swiper slider source:

```
http://pastebin.com/ggN3TqgA
```

year.html (taken from listview in the source code)

```
http://pastebin.com/ibKKUJ54
```

I understand that the routing is done with Ajax and i've edited the source code of the kitchen sink ios slider and added a link and it worked fine.

I'm not sure why my project is blocking the link. I've tried:

```
mainView.router.loadPage('year.html');
```

in my-app.js but to no avail. Anyone know why?

Comment: Is year.html in the same directory or you are loading it from a remote URL? can you please make your whole example on http://jsfiddle.net so I can help you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u28e4yd0/

Comment: year.html is same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with the slider, you forgot the main `page` class which is the index page, it is important to let ajax know where to render the new page `year.html` data.

Just add:

```
    <div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
        <div data-page="index" class="page">
```

before the slider, and do not forget to close the 2 DIVs before the `</body>` tag.

[image]